# Data can't be displayed: Angular 2

Tags: angular

I'm starting to work with angular 2. I am trying to retrieve data from a json file and display it on a html page, but this isn't working even if I try to display it in the console.

This is my service method:

```
getScheduleDay (day: string) {
    return this.http.get('http://cfp.devoxx.be/api/conferences/DV16/schedules/'.concat(day))
              .toPromise()
              .then((res: Response) => <Slot[]> res.json().slots)
              .then(slots => { console.log(slots); return slots;});
}
```

And this is the component method:

```
getScheduleDay(day: string) {
    this.scheduleListService.getScheduleDay(day);
}
```

Comment: What does the view binding look like that you use to view the data?

Comment: You don't seem to do anything with the result of calling `getScheduleDay`; how did you *expect* the value to get into the template?

Comment: And do you at least see the slots in the console? Has devoxx authorized CORS from your domain?

Comment: Any error message?

Comment: hi frinds so the biggest probleme that i have now is that my browser crashes when i try to display the data on the html component and this is the url to consume : http://cfp.devoxx.be/api/conferences/DV16/schedules/wednesday

Comment: there is some relations with the size of the json file or what so i tried to consume the schedule and display it on a html file.PS : i used angular material tabs to display every day's schedule content so it be like the name of tabs is the days of devoxx conferences